# How do I do Xdcc downloads on the command line?

Tags: irssi

I need a command line Irc client (e.g. Irssi) that can download files from a Xdcc bot.
I already tried Irssi, joined the channel and requested a file from the Xdcc bot using the usual `/msg botname xdcc send #123`, and the bot offered the file, but it said: `Please set your client to receive the file.` I already searched for an answer, but I couldn't find anything on how to accept files on a Xdcc download.
So, how do I download files from a Xdcc bot using Irssi or another command line client?
Also, which port do I have to open in my firewall for a Xdcc download?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to `/dcc get botname`; or set `dcc_autoget` to on.
The first is the command to accept files being sent to you.
The second is a setting to auto accept files being sent to you (which can be abused by others).

I suggest reading irssi's [documentation](http://irssi.org/documentation), and reading about [DCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Client-to-Client) so you realize that [XDCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDCC) is just a bot using DCC.

Comment: Thanks, this works :D I had already read the Wikipedia pages on dcc and xdcc, but neither says a single word about how to accept files. The irssi manual doesn't say anything about it either, hence my question here.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `dcc_autoget` to `on`:

```
/SET dcc_autoget ON
```

And [`add`](http://irssi.org/documentation/settings#dcc_autoget_masks) bot to white list:

```
/SET dcc_autoget_masks BOT_NAME
```

Then only bot will can send you files without confirmation.